# Fix header of table without thead with scroll bar

Tags: c#, fixed-header-tables

I have the following structure:

```
<div>
<table>  
<tbody>
<tr> 
<th>1</th> 
<!--and some columns-->  
</tr>
<!--some datarows-->
<tr>
<td></td> <!--a lot of columns-->
</tr>
</tbody>
<table>
</div>
```

I want to fix the header.

I got number of links but all they having thead in structure as I am table control in C# can't have control over the structure and also I cannot re-write html markup dynamically (not allowed).

Now I can easily fix the tableheaderrow with style

```
position : fixed
```

But table contains scroll bars so the header comes outside the panel.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you mind if jquery used for this?

Comment: anything i want to just fixed the header

Comment: i just gave the style position fixed

Comment: please see the structure, the link contains thead and in my structure there is no thead

Comment: if you don't have the header row then what you want to fix? please give your full code.

Comment: there is first row th

Comment: try this http://bit.ly/1fcNNMG. otherwise i am out of this.

Comment: The structure i posted is dynamically generated by table control of c#, so i dont have any control over to change , otherwise i would not have posted here